# iPhone with a random MAC address will not be allowed to join a Wi-Fi network

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, mac-address

There is following equipment:

1. iPhone SE that wants to connect a Wi-Fi network and generates every time a random MAC address
2. a router that not belongs to me, with Wi-Fi access point that won't let anything to join its Wi-Fi unless its MAC address is known

In order to be successfully connected to Wi-Fi iPhone needs that its address is entered into the router's MAC address table.

Admin of the router cannot register the MAC address because it is random. It is the strict policy of organization and there is no way to bypass it.

I cannot change the random MAC address to the fixed one because in order to do so the Wi-Fi network should be saved in iPhone first.

In order to save the network iPhone requires that it should successfully connect to this network first.

Etc.

Is there some solution on iPhone side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable Private Addressing *before* your first connection.

If you can see the access point in 'other networks' you can access it from there. The setting is in the ⓘ button.

[image]

btw, the 'Privacy Warning' is what you see once you are connected with Private Addressing switched off.